# Maximization problem with constraints in R

Tags: r, constraints, maximize

I have a maximization problem under certain constraints.
I have 3 different players on a string. They each have to ‘announce’ an amount `(x)` of `(e)` to consume. They all have the same utility function being `u(x)=srqt(x)`
Now I want to maximize the sum of all `u(x)=srqt(x)` (player 1, player 2 and player 3). However, the choice of x for player 2 depends on the choice of player 1, and the choice of player 3 depends on the choice of player 2 (and thereby indirectly the choice of player 1). (As an example: player 1 has `e=3` but chooses `x=2`, now player 2 has `x=2 + the difference between x1 and e1, in this case 1`)

Therefore the following constraints:

`x1<=e1`

`x1+x2<=e1+e2`

`x1+x2+x3<=e1+e2+e3-x1-x2`

and

`x1+x2+x3=sum(e)`

with all e: `0<=e<=10` (e being a randomly generated number between 0 and 10)

As an example:

`e1=4, e2=1, e3=2, e4=1`

In this case, to maximize `sum(u(x)=sqrt(x))` player 1 will announce `x1=2` giving `sqrt(2)= 1.41` and therefore sends 2 units down the line.

Player 2 now faces: `x2<=e1+e2-x1 => x2<=4+1-2` and will choose `x2=2` to maximize `sum(u(x)=sqrt(x))` and thus send 1 unit down the line

Player 3 will then face `x3=e1+e2+e3-x1-x2 => x3<=4+1+2-2-2` and will choose `x3=2` and send 1 unit down the line.

At this point player 4 does not have any chose but for the understanding: player 4 faces `x4<=e1+e2+e3+e4-x1-x2-x3 => x4<=4+1+2+1-2-2-2` and will choose `x4=2`

The tricky part for me is that the following players choice depends on the former’s choice and I really seem to struggle with the coding for this.
Any idea how to maximize u(x) giving this problem?

Comment: If you're unsure about how to formulate this problem in R, then the ORSE might be a better place to ask this question: https://or.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `DEoptim` package for differential evolution.

Fitness function:

```
fn <- function(x){
  
  if(any(cumsum(x) > ps)) return(Inf)
  
  -(sum(sqrt(x)) + sqrt(e_sum - sum(x)))
}
```

`if` tests if your vector passes all conditions (except last one which is deterministic). Minus sign is because `DEoptim` minimizes. `ps` are partial sums of vector `e` except the last sum and `e_sum` is sum of vector `e`.

```
e <- c(4, 1, 2, 1)
ps <- cumsum(e[-length(e)])
e_sum <- sum(e)

x <- DEoptim::DEoptim(
  fn = fn,
  lower = rep(0, length(e) - 1),
  upper = ps 
)

res <- c(x$optim$bestmem, e_sum - sum(x$optim$bestmem))
```

It is not clear if you are searching for integer solution. In this case it ends up as integers.

```
> res
par1 par2 par3      
   2    2    2    2
```

**EDIT**

If you remove `trace = FALSE` you would see that algorithm didn't manage to find any **feasible** solution (best fitness value is infinity). You should try to create your own initial population which will contain some feasible solutions. For example you can try something like:

```
NP <- 200
initial_sol <- e[-length(e)]
initialPop <- rbind(
  initial_sol,
  Reduce(rbind, lapply(seq_len(NP-1), function(x) abs(initial_sol + rnorm(length(initial_sol)))))
)
```

and add `initialpop= initialPop` in `DEoptim.control`.

You can also create function to create all initial solutions feasible:

```
createFesibleIndividual <- function(ps){
  
  individual <- numeric(length(ps))
  cur_sum <- 0
  for(i in seq_along(individual)){
    
    new_ele <- runif(1, 0, ps[i] - cur_sum)
    cur_sum <- cur_sum + new_ele
    individual[[i]] <- new_ele
  }
  
  individual
}

initialPop <- Reduce(rbind, lapply(seq_len(NP), function(x) createFesibleIndividual(ps)))
```

Comment: Hi, this was very helpful and appreciated - thanks. However, I do now how some problems with multiple e's/agents. I have posted the problem as an answer as there is not enough space in the comment box. I have used your code and tweaked it a little to better fit my full problem. Perhaps you know how to solve this problem?

Comment: check edit in my answer and also you can put `upper = ps`